# Web.config - use application requestLimits

Tags: web-config, request, limit

I have a page where user can Upload file to the server. I specified the

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="512000"></requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

in my Web.config but I still get an error that request is too big. I found one solution - change system file applicationHost.config. I set

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="512000000">
```

and it solved my problem. But we can't modify this file on out Dev server. I found some solutions e.g. use

```
<clear/>
```

or

```
<remove name="...">
```

in my Web.config

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <clear/>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="512000"></requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

but now I get

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to set

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

instead. That's 2GB - which I think is the maximum.

Comment: I have maxRequestLength="512000" but when I try to upload file bigger than 30MB I get an Error that request length is too big.

Comment: OH... it's my mistake. Instead of maxAllowedContentLength="512000" it should be maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"(~500MB)